# jquery - manipulate text within an element

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how do I move "Chapter Title" up to beside "1.1" so that it reads ... "1.1 Chapter Title" while leaving everything else the same?

```
<p>
  1.1
  <a name="_Toc159407685"></a>
  <a name="_Toc161121797"></a>
  <a name="_Toc208282996"></a>
  <a name="_Toc315779471"></a>
  <a href="link.jpg">
  <img class="img" alt="" src="link.jpg">
  </a>
  Chapter Title
</p>
```

Comment: There must be something missing from this question. Why do you want to do that rather than just editing it manually?

Comment: how did "Chapter title" get there?

Comment: It got there because Microsoft Word generates terrible html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you are:

```
$("p").append($("p *").detach());​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MwDc6/

Comment: This isn't going to work in my complex document, however, I've accepted and will re-ask properly ...

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a plain-JavaScript approach:

```
function moveTitle(el) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var titleNode = el.lastChild,
            title = document.createTextNode(titleNode.nodeValue.trim()),
            number = el.firstChild;
        el.removeChild(titleNode);
        el.insertBefore(title, number.nextSibling);
    }
}

moveTitle(document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tddvM/1/).

Though this does make some assumptions:

- The title you want to  move will *always* be the last child of the element,
- That last-child will *always* be a `textNode`, and
- You will *always* want to move the title to a position following the first child of element.

These assumptions can, of course, be changed or be made adaptable; but given your stated requirements it should suffice for your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$('p:contains("1.1")').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    txt = text.replace(new RegExp("chapter title", "g"), '');
    txt = text.replace(new RegExp("1.1", "g"), '1.1 chapter title');
    $(this).html(txt);
});
```